# Eliminar un elemento de un objeto JSON - PHP

Tags: php, json

Tengo un archivo JSON como éste:

```
[
 {
  "NAME": "Algo",
  "ALIAS": "Algo"
 },
 {
  "NAME": "Otro",
  "ALIAS": "Otra cosa"
 }
]
```

Necesito eliminar el segundo elemento teniendo ya el número de index (son muchos más elementos (urls)). Como hago esto?
Intenté manualmente `unset($this->db[1])` pero no funcionó.

#### Codigo utilizado

```
$this->db = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::DB_PATH), true);
$index_num = 0;
foreach($this->db as $url) {
$index_num++;
if($url['ALIAS'] == $this->alias) {
unset($url[$index_num]);
}
}
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: El unset debería funcionar en la variable hacia donde haces `json_decode`, claro, esto no cambia al archivo json. Puedes colocar una muestra del código que utilizas?

Comment: @solarc Actualizado.

Comment: estas haciendo unset a `$url[$index_num]` en lugar de `$this->db[$index_num]`.

Comment: @solarc no funciona..

Comment: Si no funciona prueba usar una key en el bucle y darle unset a eso: `$this->db as $k => $url` y luego `unset($this->db[$k])`.

Comment: @solarc Eso funcionó, gracias, pero me explicas como key en el bucle? Y porque funciona $k = url si no es array => key, son varias urls.

Comment: Si usas `$key => $value` en un bucle foreach, `$key` será el índice con el cual acceder al item en tu array. Imagino que tu índice no es exactamente 0, 1, 2...., si usas $key, tendrás el índice exacto que deberías de usar. Y de paso te ahorras los `$index_num++`.

Comment: @solarc entiendo, mi indice era 4593

Comment: @solarc creo que sería bueno que publiques una respuesta con la solución para que la pregunta no quede abierta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

aquí  tu código en el  que corregí el error, ya un compañero se dio cuenta, solo que no se animo a corregirlo

```
$this->db = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::DB_PATH), true);
$index_num = 0;
$aux=$this->db;//$aux innecesario
foreach($aux as $key => $url) {

     if($url['ALIAS'] == $this->alias) {
          unset($this->db[$key]);
          }

     $index_num++;//innecesario,
     }
unset($aux);
```

O bien para no ocupar tanta memoria por un instante:

```
$this->db = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::DB_PATH), true);
$index_num = 0;
$aux=[];
foreach($this->db as $key => $url) {

     if($url['ALIAS'] == $this->alias) {
                 $aux[]=$key;
          }


    }
 foreach($aux as $index){unset($this->db[$index]);}
```

La otrra es usar array_filter:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Para qué $aux?? Intenté lo que me dijo @solarc pero no funcionó

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia un problema parecido pero lo pude reparar de la siguiente forma, me tomo mucho tiempo arreglarlo aprox unas 2 hrs. pero aqui te dejo mi codigo:

```
$datos_usuarios= file_get_contents("_Notifications.json");

        $json = json_decode($datos_usuarios, true);
        foreach($json as $usuarioJson=>$val)
        {
            if($val['UserId']==$usuario)
            {
                unset($json[$usuarioJson]);
            }
        }
        file_put_contents("_Notifications.json", json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```